# Function outside of ng-view being called on ng-view change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that is outside of the scope of `ng-view` but it is being called every time that a change to the `ng-view` is being made.

```
<div id="header" ng-controller="menuController">
    <div id="menu" ng-if="showmenu">
        <ul id="mainmenu">
            ...
        </ul>
        {{ menu() }}
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="bodyController">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

In this case, every time I navigate, using an item in `#mainmenu` that changes the template within `ng-view`, the `menuController.menu()` function is being called.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because of digest cycle, which may be triggered by many things. As soon as digest/apply cycle is triggered on your scope, you will see that `menu()` function is getting called.

Most state change in angular will trigger a digest cycle like clicking on links etc.

Comment: How would I prevent that?

Comment: If you think that menu() shouldn't be called after initialization or after any scope change you can use one way binding {{::menu()}}. However please note that one way binding is supported in angular 1.3 versions.